Error when integrating firebase in react-native expo, written in typescript
I installed firebase , initialized it, linked my react-native expo project to firebase realtime database and configured it.
I was expecting my web application to work seamlessly but after installing and initializing firebase in my react-native expo project, i keep getting the error::
Static Rendering Error (Node.js)
window is not defined
Call Stack
getOrCreateDataLayer
node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js
factory
node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js
Component.instanceFactory
node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js
Provider.getOrInitializeService
node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/index.cjs.js
Provider.initialize
node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/index.cjs.js
initializeAnalytics
node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js
getAnalytics
node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js
factory


Any updates? Did you manage to solve this?
